# "unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long" when I'm trying to use chmod command

Tags: command-line

This is how it happened:

```
julian@JulianNB:~$ sudo chmod 644 ~/音樂/* 
[sudo] password for julian: 
julian@JulianNB:~$ sudo chmod 755 ~/音樂/*/
julian@JulianNB:~$ sudo chmod 644 ~/音樂/*/*
sudo: unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long
```

I just want to set 755 to every folder and 644 to every music files in the ~/音樂/

Comment: This is because of the Chinese character. It is a bug in **chmod** and not elementary OS

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
find ~/音樂/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find ~/音樂/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I have set this as alias in my ~/.bashrc

```
alias fixpermissions="find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;"
```